# XQUERY: optimizing a query that touches large collections

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db

I have the following XQUERY running in ExistDB (against XML documents that follow the TEI schema):

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";

let $data-collection := "/db/apps/deheresi/resources/documents"
let $people-collection := "/db/apps/deheresi/resources/documents/codes_people.xml"

for $msdoc in collection($data-collection)/tei:TEI[contains(@xml:id,'ms609')]

for $ordinal in $msdoc/tei:text/tei:front//tei:div[@type='registry_ordinal']/replace(@n, '#', '')

for $doctype in $msdoc/tei:text/tei:front//tei:div[@type='doc_type']/replace(@subtype, '#', '')

for $folio in $msdoc/tei:text/tei:front//tei:div[@type='folio']/replace(@n, '#', '')

for $nameref in $msdoc/tei:text/tei:body[1]/tei:p[1]/tei:seg[1]/tei:persName[@role = 'dep']/replace(@nymRef, '#', '') 

for $persname in normalize-space(string-join(doc($people-collection)//tei:person[@xml:id = $nameref]))

return concat('<td>',$ordinal,'</td><td>',$folio,'</td><td>',$doctype,'</td><td>',$persname,'</td>')
```

Organization of XML documents:

- There are 700+ TEI documents, each with `<TEI xml:id="foo_1.xml">` as the root node (document identifier increments foo_1.xml, foo_2.xml, foo_3.xml, etc.) (always in the same place)
- Each TEI document contains a single unique element identifying a person `<persName role="dep" nymRef="#unique_foo_name">` (not always in the same place in a  document)
- A separate XML document `codes_people.xml` that contains 1500+ xml:ids of distinct people

The function does the following:

1. get the identifying `tei:TEI/@xml:id` and the `tei:persName[@role="dep"]/@nymRef` from each xml document
2. With the `tei:persName[@role="dep"]/@nymRef` I look up the the name in `codes_people.xml/tei:person/xml:id="unique_foo_name"`

This all returns the expected results...except it's really, really slow (4 seconds). Obviously I'm testing on a local computer and not a server, but I would like to optimize the queries before testing on more powerful servers.

ADDED PER REQUEST:

ExistDB version : 3.3.0

Sample output (the eventual target is an HTML table)

```
<td>0001</td><td>1r</td><td>Deposition</td><td>Arnald Garnier</td> 
<td>0002</td><td>1r</td><td>Deposition</td><td>Guilhem de Rosengue</td> 
<td>0003</td><td>1r</td><td>Deposition</td><td>Hugo de Mamiros</td> 
<td>0004</td><td>1r</td><td>Deposition</td><td>P Lapassa senior</td>
```

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've added more information in a self-response below, and a link to all the files in Dropbox in the comments.

Comment: I optimised one piece of code, changing `$nameref` to refer to `in $msdoc/` instead of going through the collection again. It's a bit fast but still not ideal.

Comment: Two questions to help me understand your environment: Which version of eXist? Have you defined any indexes on the collections containing this TEI data? Lastly, can you add one example of what an expected result is for this query?

Comment: I've added the exist DB version and some sample output. I've also update the code to reflect the fastest version I've tested - and perhaps easier for you to read. Finally, I haven't added indexes yet...

Comment: I added `<range>` and `<fulltext>`  to `<index xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">` in the config file. Re-indexed and reran the Xquery with the Query Prolifer on. It tells me that it used `range`but `optimization = no index`. Introducing these indexes did not improve the query speed.

Comment: Is the data available so that we can test and optimise?

Comment: Also there are so many `for` loops, that it is hard to understand the cardinality of your join relationships without seeing representative data. However, I doubt you really need that many loops!

Comment: I've put the xml files into a .zip available here https://www.dropbox.com/s/2b8kw8b3pvpks4j/stackoverflowdocs.zip?dl=0

Comment: The first 5 `for` loops traverse the same document getting a variety of attribute values, the 6th then does a look-up and retrieval from another document (getting a printable name from text() values). If I remove the 6th `for` loop the query executes in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: I've added a bounty to this question...following up my posting the data files requested. Hopefully someone identifies a solution (taking into account the simplifications I posted in response below). Solutions involving Xquery and eXist indexing are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a few problems with your code, that impact performance. The first is the fact that you process strings instead of xml paths. e.g. when using `replace()` instead of of `some/@path[. = 'xyz']`. Simply by using `fn:id()` instead of `replace()` will cut execution times to under 1 second.

The second is a missing xmlschema namespace declaration in your index config file, not that those indexes are used, since you are forcing exist to process strings instead of xml.

The third is the fact that your xquery code does not return a well-formed xml fragment, always a bad idea for performance reasons.

```
xquery version "3.1";
declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";

declare variable $data-collection := "/db/apps/so-52709411/data";

(:always return a well-formed fragment:)
 <table>{

 let $people-collection := doc($data-collection || "/codes_people.xml")

 let $msdoc := collection($data-collection)//tei:TEI[contains(@xml:id,'ms609')]

 for $n in $msdoc
 let $registry := $n//tei:div[@type='registry_ordinal']/data(@n)
 let $type := $n//tei:div[@type='doc_type']/data(@subtype)
 let $folio := $n//tei:div[@type='folio']/data(@n)
 let $nym := substring-after($n//tei:persName[@role = 'dep']/data(@nymRef), '#') 
 let $persName := $people-collection//id($nym)/tei:persName

 return
<tr>
<td>{$registry}</td>
<td>{$type}</td>
<td>{$folio}</td>
<td>{$persName/string()
}</td>
</tr>

}
 </table>
```

combined with

```
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
<index xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <range>
       <create qname="tei:persName" type="xs:string"/>
       <create qname="tei:person" type="xs:string"/>
       <create qname="@type" type="xs:string"/>
       <create qname="@role" type="xs:string"/>
       <create qname="@nymRef" type="xs:string"/>
    </range>
</index>
<triggers>
    <trigger class="org.exist.extensions.exquery.restxq.impl.RestXqTrigger"/>
</triggers>
 </collection>
```

results in indexes actually being usable

[image: /Users/HALmob/pCloud Drive/Screenshots/Screen Shot 2018-10-15 at 01.30.42.png]

but the data sample isn't really big enough to make much of a performance impact beyond the rewritten xquery. So even without indexes you should be running in the less then 1s range (depending on memory, hardware etc, YMMV)

you can download a working app running with your code [here](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZzn3n7ZvSMUXeOLKufgd5Oj0SqXLQ2njtw7)

Comment: This is a really helpful answer, thank you for spending time not only to help along the code but also to explain some fundamental errors. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simplify the Xquery by replacing certain `for` loops with `let` and `concat()`:

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";

declare variable $people-collection := doc("/db/apps/deheresi/resources/documents/codes_people.xml");

let $data-collection := "/db/apps/deheresi/resources/documents"

for $msdoc in collection($data-collection)/tei:TEI[contains(@xml:id,'ms609')]

    let $concat1 := concat('<td>',
               $msdoc//tei:div[@type='registry_ordinal']/replace(@n, '#', ''), 
               '</td><td>', 
               $msdoc//tei:div[@type='doc_type']/replace(@subtype, '#', ''), 
               '</td><td>',
               $msdoc//tei:div[@type='folio']/replace(@n, '#', ''),
               '</td><td>')

    (:  obtain the attribute value of persName[@role = 'dep']/@nymRef   :)
    let $nameref := $msdoc//tei:persName[@role = 'dep']/replace(@nymRef, '#', '') 

    (:  now use the attribute value to lookup a printable name using xml:id in document codes_people.xml :)
    let $persname := normalize-space(string-join($people-collection//tei:person[@xml:id = $nameref]))

return concat($concat1,$persname,'</td>')
```

These adjustments removed .5 seconds from the query execution time (now 3.5 seconds).

If I strip out the final lookup (`$persname`) the query executes in .17 seconds. The lookup to the file `codes_people.xml` appears to be the bottle neck.

EDIT: I've added the following indexes affecting the relevant elements and they have not produced any optimisations

```
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
    <index xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
        <range>
           <create qname="tei:persName" type="xs:string"/>
           <create qname="tei:person" type="xs:string"/>
        </range>
    </index>
    <triggers>
        <trigger class="org.exist.extensions.exquery.restxq.impl.RestXqTrigger"/>
    </triggers>
</collection>
```

View from Query Profiler:

[image: View from Query Profiler]

Comment: Depending on the size of codes_people.xml, it might be worth simply loading that as your $people-collection variable and save repeatedly loading the document.

Comment: I've updated the example using @chrisis 's suggestion, but it does not affect performance.